# Generate a table with interval of months in a year -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a table in the below format:-

```
TS_RANGE_BEGIN      TS_RANGE_END    
2019-01-01 17:00:00 2019-01-31 17:00:00  
2019-02-01 17:00:00 2019-02-28 17:00:00  
2019-03-01 17:00:00 2019-03-31 17:00:00
```

Could you please help on this?

Thanks,

Comment: You should be more specific with your question.  Are you asking about `dml` , `ddl`, data generation , something else ? [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a simple row generator:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with std (datum) as
  2    (select to_date('01.01.2019 17:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual)
  3  select add_months(datum, level - 1) ts_range_begin,
  4         add_months(datum, level) - 1 ts_range_end
  5  from std
  6  connect by level <= 12;

TS_RANGE_BEGIN      TS_RANGE_END
------------------- -------------------
2019-01-01 17:00:00 2019-01-31 17:00:00
2019-02-01 17:00:00 2019-02-28 17:00:00
2019-03-01 17:00:00 2019-03-31 17:00:00
2019-04-01 17:00:00 2019-04-30 17:00:00
2019-05-01 17:00:00 2019-05-31 17:00:00
2019-06-01 17:00:00 2019-06-30 17:00:00
2019-07-01 17:00:00 2019-07-31 17:00:00
2019-08-01 17:00:00 2019-08-31 17:00:00
2019-09-01 17:00:00 2019-09-30 17:00:00
2019-10-01 17:00:00 2019-10-31 17:00:00
2019-11-01 17:00:00 2019-11-30 17:00:00
2019-12-01 17:00:00 2019-12-31 17:00:00

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The `STD` CTE is used to set starting date.